# stating number of characters in regex

Tags: php, regex, validation

I want that the usernames be 4-32 chars long.

```
function validate_username($input)
{
    return (bool) preg_match('/^([a-z]+[a-z0-9_]*){4,32}$/i', $input);
}
```

What is wrong with my try, please?

`var_dump(validate_username('h_q8Y'));` which returns `FALSE`

But `var_dump(validate_username('h_q8Yewre_'));` returns `TRUE`

Comment: And why not this? $l = strlen($input); if(4 <= $l && $l <= 32) ...

Comment: do you want to match UPPERCASE characters too?

Comment: @full.stack.ex you are right, but I preferred to use a regex style length checker.

Comment: Yes, I want it @shiplu.mokadd.im .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{4,32}` repeats the inner paranthesis match 4 times. You need at least 4 letters to satisfy it.

To assert the length you need a lookahead assertion which is independent from the character class specifier:

```
 preg_match('/^(?=.{4,32})([a-z]+[a-z0-9_]*)$/i'

                   |             |
             asserts length      |
                            checks char mix
```

Comment: +1 but this is a little over complex for what's actually required here - why not just validate the first character, and then validate the remaining `{3,31}` characters?

Comment: Will this allow for capitals? I thought they had to be specified with A-Z?

Comment: @MrFox the `/i` flag makes it case-insensitive

Comment: @DaveRandom: Yes, a bit unneccessary in this case. But I presume splitting the conditions up is less confusing to OP, despite the syntax overhead. He was just mixing up where it applies to groups.

Comment: Dear @mario thank you very much for this answer. Wish I could set all the three answers as the right answer! You tought me what I exactly looked for.

Answer (score 3):

You are repeating your repetition 4 to 32 times. I assume that you wanted to make sure that the username starts with a letter. In this case, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]\w{3,31}$/i', $input);
```

Note that `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your **regular expression is wrong**. Here

- `([a-z]+[a-z0-9_]*)` matches `h_q8Y`.
- Then `{4,32}` means there will be **at least 4** or **at most 32** of `h_q8Y`. But you provided only one `h_q8Y`.

Hence its not working.

Its better you use following expression.

```
/^[a-z]\w{3,31}$/i
```